# Button not working, with .addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm creating simple HTML programs with JavaScript. The buttons aren't working when I click on it. Here is my code:

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1> A random machine</h1>
    <p>
      Include floating-point number
    </p>
    <p>
      Want an integer? Click here!
    </p>
    <button id="integerChanges" type="button"> Click me! </button>
    <p>
      Enter an integer/floating-point number here (start point, included):
      <input placeholder="Random number" id="a">
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
      Enter another integer/floating-point number here (end point, not included):
      <input placeholder="Random number" id="b">
    </p>
    <button id="submit"> Submit </button>
    <script>
          document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function() {callX()})
    document.getElementById("integerChanges").addEventListener("click", function() {
      window.location.href="integer.html"
    })
      a = document.getElementById("a")
      b = document.getElementById("b")
      a.parseInt()
      b.parseInt()
      if (a > b) {
        throw "start point > end point  "
        window.location.href="retakeHandler.html"
        
      }

      function callX() {
        var x = Math.random(document.getElementById("a"), document.getElementById("b"));
        console.log(x);
        document.querySelector("html").innerHTML = x;
      };
      function callX2() {
        var x2 = Math.floor((Math.random(a,b)) * 10 + 1);
        document.querySelector("html").innerHTML = x2;
      };

      function retakeForm_error() {
        var buttonRetake = document.createElement
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*integer.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1> A random machine</h1>
    <p>
      Include floating-point number
    </p>
    <p>
      Want an integer? Click here!
    </p>
    <button id="integerChanges" type="button"> Click me! </button>
    <p>
      Enter an integer/floating-point number here (start point, included):
      <input placeholder="Random number" id="a">
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>
      Enter another integer/floating-point number here (end point, not included):
      <input placeholder="Random number" id="b">
    </p>
    <button id="submit"> Submit </button>
    <script>
          document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function() {callX()})
    document.getElementById("integerChanges").addEventListener("click", function() {
      window.location.href="integer.html"
    })
      a = document.getElementById("a")
      b = document.getElementById("b")
      a.parseInt()
      b.parseInt()
      if (a > b) {
        throw "start point > end point  "
        window.location.href="retakeHandler.html"
        
      }

      function callX() {
        var x = Math.random(document.getElementById("a"), document.getElementById("b"));
        console.log(x);
        document.querySelector("html").innerHTML = x;
      };
      function callX2() {
        var x2 = Math.floor((Math.random(a,b)) * 10 + 1);
        document.querySelector("html").innerHTML = x2;
      };

      function retakeForm_error() {
        var buttonRetake = document.createElement
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*retakeHandler.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>
      Error: start point > end point
    </h1>
    <p id="retakeForm"></p>
    <script>
      function retake() {
        var myP = document.getElementById("retakeForm");
                 
        // creating button element
        var button = document.createElement('BUTTON');
                 
        // creating text to be
        //displayed on button
        var text = document.createTextNode("Click me");
                 
                // appending text to button
        button.appendChild(text);
                 
                // appending button to div
        myP.appendChild(button); ;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Edited many versions (this is version 3 or 4 now) and added files

Public on Repl.it with name: ElectronicFatherlySale

Notes:

- Code isn't done

Please help me and explain why this happens?

Comment: What is `document.getElementById("a") = a;` supposed to do? (It's an error that would be reported in your browser's console).

Comment: that's the starting point number. I'm running this in trinket

Comment: It isn't a number. It's an attempt to assign the value of a variable (which looks like it is an input element) to the return value of a function … which isn't allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I see few small mistakes in your code:

- `document.getElementById("a") = a;` does not mean anything, because you are trying to set a value to something cannot be modified
- You have declared two functions, `callX` and `callX2`, but you never call them. I suggest you to do the following first:

--

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function () {
        callX();
        callX2();
    })
    function callX() {
        var x = Math.random(document.getElementById("a"), document.getElementById("b"));
        console.log(x);
        document.querySelector("html").innerHTML = x;
    };
    function callX2() {
        document.getElementById("integerChanges").addEventListener("click", function () {
            var x2 = Math.floor((Math.random(a, b)) * 10 + 1);
            document.querySelector("html").innerHTML = x2;
        })
    };
</script>
```